# UIGesture LongPress duplicating cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Experiencing a weird interaction flaw with my UI for my tableview cell. I implemented a long press gesture:

```
func handleLongPress(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {

    var myCharacters: SelectedCharacter?
    let localLongPress = sender as UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    let locationInView = localLongPress.locationInView(cardsListed)
    let indexPath = charactersListed.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)
    let listed = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Characters
    let cell: firstCharacterDetails = charactersListed.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! firstCharacterDetails

    if listed == 0 {

    } else {

                if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
                    print("Long press Ended")
                } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
                    let bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                    let screenHeight: NSNumber = bounds.size.height
                    if screenHeight == 480 {
                        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let characterDetailsController: CharacterDetailsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("characterDetails") as! CharacterDetailsViewController
                        characterDetailsController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
                        let popoverplayersCharacterController = characterDetailsController.popoverPresentationController
                        popoverCharacterNoteController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
                        popoverCharacterNoteController?.delegate = self
                        popoverCharacterNoteController?.sourceView = cell.cardDescription
                        characterDetailsController.characterDetails = listed
                        self.presentViewController(characterDetailsController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

this is an example sorry if the coding isn't complete as I just took out this area of code for reference. Now my issue is one that is quite unique and is only likely to happen on accidental gestures by the user but for the safety of the user I would like to remove this problem.

The issue I am facing is that when the user longpress gestures a selected cell if they accidentally drag to another cell with their finger while still holding the cell will actually duplicate itself or drag itself below the cell that the user long press gestured dragged to. I am unsure how to handle preventing this from happening but if anyone has any insight it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Discovered what I was doing wrong. After looking at the code a second time through I realized calling the dequeueResuableCell was the incorrect function to use. I switch the line of code with:

```
let cell: firstCharacterDetails = charactersListed.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! firstCharacterDetails
```

and problem solved. I wasn't think about much when I copy and pasted some of my code that I reused in a few different controllers.